# QueryStringModule with FriendlyUrls does not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, query-string, friendly-url

Good morning, I need to encrypt my querystring and i found an interesting method in this [link](https://madskristensen.net/blog/httpmodule-for-query-string-encryption/) and I convert it in vb.net:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public Class QueryStringModule
    Implements IHttpModule

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IHttpModule.Dispose
    End Sub

    Public Sub Init(ByVal context As HttpApplication) Implements IHttpModule.Init
        AddHandler context.BeginRequest, New EventHandler(AddressOf context_BeginRequest)
    End Sub

    Private Const PARAMETER_NAME As String = "enc="
    Private Const ENCRYPTION_KEY As String = "key"

    Private Sub context_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim context As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current

        If context.Request.Url.OriginalString.Contains("aspx") AndAlso context.Request.RawUrl.Contains("?") Then
            Dim query As String = ExtractQuery(context.Request.RawUrl)
            Dim path As String = GetVirtualPath()

            If query.StartsWith(PARAMETER_NAME, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
                Dim rawQuery As String = query.Replace(PARAMETER_NAME, String.Empty)
                Dim decryptedQuery As String = Decrypt(rawQuery)
                context.RewritePath(path, String.Empty, decryptedQuery)
            ElseIf context.Request.HttpMethod = "GET" Then
                Dim encryptedQuery As String = Encrypt(query)
                context.Response.Redirect(path & encryptedQuery)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function GetVirtualPath() As String
        Dim path As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl
        path = path.Substring(0, path.IndexOf("?"))
        path = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("/") + 1)
        Return path
    End Function

    Private Shared Function ExtractQuery(ByVal url As String) As String
        Dim index As Integer = url.IndexOf("?") + 1
        Return url.Substring(index)
    End Function

    Private ReadOnly Shared SALT As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ENCRYPTION_KEY.Length.ToString())

    Public Shared Function Encrypt(ByVal inputText As String) As String
        Dim rijndaelCipher As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged()
        Dim plainText As Byte() = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(inputText)
        Dim SecretKey As PasswordDeriveBytes = New PasswordDeriveBytes(ENCRYPTION_KEY, SALT)

        Using encryptor As ICryptoTransform = rijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor(SecretKey.GetBytes(32), SecretKey.GetBytes(16))

            Using memoryStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()

                Using cryptoStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                    cryptoStream.Write(plainText, 0, plainText.Length)
                    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
                    Return "?" & PARAMETER_NAME & Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray())
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function

    Public Shared Function Decrypt(ByVal inputText As String) As String
        Dim rijndaelCipher As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged()
        Dim encryptedData As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(inputText)
        Dim secretKey As PasswordDeriveBytes = New PasswordDeriveBytes(ENCRYPTION_KEY, SALT)

        Using decryptor As ICryptoTransform = rijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor(secretKey.GetBytes(32), secretKey.GetBytes(16))

            Using memoryStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(encryptedData)

                Using cryptoStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
                    Dim plainText As Byte() = New Byte(encryptedData.Length - 1) {}
                    Dim decryptedCount As Integer = cryptoStream.Read(plainText, 0, plainText.Length)
                    Return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plainText, 0, decryptedCount)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
```

but also my project use FriendlyUrls and I figured out that with FriendlyUrls the things does not working and always return the url without the extension ".aspx" but with the querystring not encrypted

```
Imports System.Web.Routing
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls

Public Module RouteConfig
    Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
        Dim settings As FriendlyUrlSettings = New FriendlyUrlSettings() With {
            .AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent
        }
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings)
    End Sub
End Module
```

of course if I set `.AutoRedirectMode` to `Off` it works but without friendlyurls.

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT 09/10/2019:

We figured out that remove the test of OriginalString.Contains("aspx") in the `context_BeginRequest` the encryption works, now the code is like:

```
Private Sub context_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim context As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current

        If context.Request.RawUrl.Contains("?") Then
            Dim query As String = ExtractQuery(context.Request.RawUrl)
            Dim path As String = GetVirtualPath()

            If query.StartsWith(PARAMETER_NAME, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
                Dim rawQuery As String = query.Replace(PARAMETER_NAME, String.Empty)
                Dim decryptedQuery As String = Decrypt(rawQuery)
                context.RewritePath(path, String.Empty, decryptedQuery)
            ElseIf context.Request.HttpMethod = "GET" Then
                Dim encryptedQuery As String = Encrypt(query)
                context.Response.Redirect(path & encryptedQuery)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

But now the question is: there is other method to target an aspx page without test the extension? I think there is a risk that targeting things that not should target like "ashx" or cache-busting code that use querystring.

Comment: BeginRequest sub is checking that url contains "aspx" - have you tried removing this check? deleting "context.Request.Url.OriginalString.Contains("aspx") AndAlso "

Comment: @SimonEvans I try and it works, but there is no risk that it test things that should not test? Like ".ashx" or chache-busting code in like `<script src="Scripts/contextmenu.js?v=<%= IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(Server.MapPath("Scripts/contextmenu.js")).ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") %>"></script>`

Comment: Yep. I was hoping to have a solution for that by the time you asked the question, but no joy. You'll need some other check to see if the request is targeting an aspx page, rather than some other resource, but I'm drawing a blank. Sorry.